# ZKTeco SDK ReadAllUserID() fails with error -115

Tags: c#, biometrics, zkteco

I'm using ZKTeco sdk to connect to a device, the connection works fine, but anything that requires reading large data fails.

ReadAllUserID fails with error -115

```
            if (!axCZKEM1.ReadAllUserID(1)) {
                Log("ReadAllUserID failed.");
                int errorCode = 0;
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref errorCode);
                Log("ErrorCode=" + errorCode); // ErrorCode=-115
            }
```

SDK: standalone+sdk-6.3.1.37-doc-2.1.0-demo-1.1.15.

OS: Windows 7 x32.

Device: Door Access, Model: ACP-260

The machine is using the new protocol (i.e. The TCP version not the old UDP version).

Comment: What device model are you using?

Comment: @RafaelBiz: Device: Door Access, Model: ACP-260

Comment: Do you mean InBio-260? If so, you should probably be using the Pull SDK instead of the Standalone SDK. It depends on wich firmware is installed on the device.

Comment: Have you verified that any function other than `Connect` works correctly?

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReadAllUserID` returns `false` because you should probably be using the **Pull SDK** instead of the **Standalone SDK**. It depends on the device model and which firmware is installed in it.

In addition to that, the `Connect` function may return a false positive because it only establishes a TCP connection and it does not guarantee that the connection is valid.